# Is JavaScript Conditional Operator better method for this if/else statement?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to see if I can reduce the code below with less JavaScript. When the user select Even dropdown option the only differences between that and the else statement is  "i = 0" and "i % 2 === 0"

any recommendations? Maybe conditional operator would be best method? thank you

```
        if (this.selection == "even") {
            for (let i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
                if (i % 2 === 0) 
                this.results.push(i + "\n");
            }
        } else {
            for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                if (i % 2 !== 0) 
                this.results.push(i + "\n");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.selection` to determine the starting number, then increment by 2 inside the loop instead of `i++`, so you don't have to check `i % 2`.

```
const startAt = this.selection == "even" ? 0 : 1;
for (let i = startAt; i <= number; i += 2) {
    this.results.push(i + "\n");
}
```

Comment: @Teemu Pretty sure this should be functionally identical to the code OP posted. Basically one or the other is selected, and it runs. They ditched the if because they `+= 2` instead of `i++`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you, works perfectly. I will be sure to continue to use Conditional Operator when applicable.